# SVG stroke gradient causes horizontal lines to display on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, svg, safari, rendering, radial-gradients

Adding a radial gradient to my SVG path seems to cause weird horizontal (anti-aliasing?) lines on some iOS devices or when you zoom in/out on an iOS device. I wasn't able to replicate it anywhere else.

Here's the (isolated) code:

```
<svg class="componentClass__chart-svg" width="335" height="318" viewBox="0 0 335 320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="axesGradient" cx="50%" cy="0%" fx="50%" fy="0%" r="50%">
      <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="10%"></stop>
      <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="100%" stop-opacity="0.2"></stop>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <path class="componentClass__axes" stroke-width="2" stroke="url(#axesGradient)" fill="none" d="M151 12 Q167 0 183 12 L319 108 Q335 120 329 139 L276 299 Q270 318 250 318 L85 318 Q65 318 59 299 L6 139 Q0 120 16 108 Z
                    M151 37 Q167 25 183 37 L293 116 Q309 128 303 147 L260 275 Q254 294 234 294 L101 294 Q81 294 75 275 L32 147 Q26 128 42 116 Z
                    M151 62 Q167 50 183 62 L267 124 Q283 136 277 155 L244 251 Q238 270 218 270 L117 270 Q97 270 91 251 L58 155 Q52 136 68 124 Z
                    M151 87 Q167 75 183 87 L241 132 Q257 144 251 163 L228 227 Q222 246 202 246 L133 246 Q113 246 107 227 L84 163 Q78 144 94 132 Z
                    M152 113 Q167 100 183 113 L215 139 Q231 152 224 171 L213 203 Q206 222 186 222 L149 222 Q129 222 122 203 L111 171 Q104 152 119 139 Z
                    " />
</svg>
```

And the issue:
[SVG showing horizontal line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R5SX.jpg)

Note this doesn't happen on every iPhone or iPad, but you're usually able to replicate it when you try zooming in and out.

I was able to nail down the issue to this particular use case: as soon as you add the gradient to the stroke, it starts happening. If you change `stroke="url(#axesGradient)` to just `stroke="#FFF"`, it doesn't seem to happen.

Is there any way I can optimize the SVG to prevent rendering issues?

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/martijnd92/pen/KKeXeLX) with the exact code above.

Comment: Looks like rounding issues; what happens if you multiply the viewBox (and everything) by 100?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Good suggestion, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to solve the issue. Or I might be doing something wrong there.

Comment: There is a difference between the aspect ratio of the width/height attributes and the width/height defined in the viewBox. Does it help to remove either the width or height attribute. Maybe even removing both and let the parent HTML element control the width or the height of the SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, but in my case these lines appeared in any browser on IOS 16, updating to IOS 16.3 fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue in the latest iOS when applying a glow effect filter on an svg shape. I eventually found that applying `overflow:visible` to the svg element solves this. I have no idea why.